# PHP callback function not being called

Tags: php, function, callback, memcached

I've got the following code:

```
function failureCallback($host, $port) {
    print "memcache '$host:$port' failed";
}

$this->memcache = new Memcache;

## bool Memcache::addServer  (  string $host  [,  int $port = 11211  [,  bool $persistent  [,  int $weight  [,  int $timeout  [,  int $retry_interval  [,  bool $status  [,  callback $failure_callback  [,  int $timeoutms  ]]]]]]]] )
 $this->memcache->addServer('192.168.1.35', '11211', FALSE, 50, 10, 10, TRUE, 'failureCallback' );
```

The server is online and running (verified!), but the Failure callback function is being called at each connection. Why is that?

Reference:

[PHP documentation:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.addserver.php) Memcache::addServer -> failure_callback

> Allows the user to specify a callback
>   function to run upon encountering an
>   error. The callback is run before
>   failover is attempted. The function
>   takes two parameters, the hostname and
>   port of the failed server

Edit: Updated post with correct number of parameters before the callback function, but without any luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.php.net/memcache.addserver says:

> Memcache::addServer
>
> [...]
> When using this method (as opposed to Memcache::connect()  and Memcache::pconnect()) the network connection is not established until actually needed.

```
class Foo {
  protected $memcache;

  public function __construct() {
    echo "Foo::construct\n";
    $this->memcache = new Memcache;
    echo "  adding server\n";
    $this->memcache->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211, false, 50, 5, 5, true, array($this, 'failureCallback'));
    echo "  constructor done\n";
  }

  public function bar($value) {
    echo "Foo::bar($value)\n";
    $b = $this->memcache->add('testkey', $value, false, 5);
    echo '  add() returned ', $b ? 'true':'false', "\n";
  }

  public function failureCallback($host, $port) {
    echo " ( Foo::failureCallback: memcache '$host:$port' failed )\n";
  }
}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->bar(1);
```

prints (with no memcached running on localhost)

```
Foo::construct
  adding server
  constructor done
Foo::bar(1)
 ( Foo::failureCallback: memcache '127.0.0.1:11211' failed )
  add() returned false
```

Comment: Hi Volker! Thanks a lot for your reply. That made a lot of sense actually!

Answer (score 3):

The reason your code doesn't work is you aren't actually passing a callback. You're just calling that function and passing the return value. A callback in PHP is usually either a string with the function name or an array for object methods.

```
$this->memcache->addServer('192.168.1.35', '11211', 0, 50, 10, TRUE, array($this, '_call_memecache_failure');
```

The parameters should be passed by the function. You can learn more about how callbacks work in PHP [in the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback)

Examples (from the docs):

```
<?php 

// An example callback function
function my_callback_function() {
    echo 'hello world!';
}

// An example callback method
class MyClass {
    static function myCallbackMethod() {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}

// Type 1: Simple callback
call_user_func('my_callback_function'); 

// Type 2: Static class method call
call_user_func(array('MyClass', 'myCallbackMethod')); 

// Type 3: Object method call
$obj = new MyClass();
call_user_func(array($obj, 'myCallbackMethod'));

// Type 4: Static class method call (As of PHP 5.2.3)
call_user_func('MyClass::myCallbackMethod');

// Type 5: Relative static class method call (As of PHP 5.3.0)
class A {
    public static function who() {
        echo "A\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function who() {
        echo "B\n";
    }
}

call_user_func(array('B', 'parent::who')); // A
?>
```

Comment: Hi Chris! Thanks a lot for an extensive reply. However, it's not working as you say. I have tried to call the callback function with both your example ( array($this, '_call_memecache_failure') ) as well as what's shown at PHP.net ( '_call_memecache_failure' ). Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Actually, straight from your excample, here's whats happen: Message: Memcache::addserver() expects parameter 7 to be boolean, array given

Comment: Looks like it's missing an argument before the callback. Double check to make sure you're calling the function correctly (I just copied your function call and changed the callback). I think you're missing the $status argument or something. I've never used memecache so I don't know what the arguments mean

Comment: Try addServer($host, $port, true, array($this, '_call_memecache');

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I had missed an argument actually. Updated my original post now, but it still doesn't call the function at an offline server...

Comment: Hi again, Nope, that didnt work either: Message: Memcache::addserver() expects parameter 4 to be long, array given

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->memcache = new Memcache;

$this->memcache->addserver(
    $host,
    $port,
    $persistent,
    $weight,
    $timeout,
    $retryInterval,
    $status,
    function($host, $tcpPort, $udpPort, $errorMessage, $errorCode) {
        $message = strtr('Memcache fail on :host (TCP::tcp/UDP::udp) with message ":msg" (:code)', [
            ':host' => $host,
            ':tcp'  => $tcpPort,
            ':udp'  => $udpPort,
            ':msg'  => $errorMessage,
            ':code' => $errorCode
        ]);

        error_log($message);
    }
);
```